# Rust panics when I inline borrow on RefCell<>

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, refcell

When I run the following line in a function, Rust panics. X is &Tree and Tree is Rc<RefCell<TreeNode<>>>. TreeNode is a struct.

```
x.borrow_mut().parent.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().left = Option::from(y.as_ref().unwrap().clone());
```

I tried changing the borrow_mut() to borrow() and leaving the second one as borrow_mut() but same error message.

Error message:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError'
```

The whole function:

```
    fn left_rotate(x: &Tree){
        let mut y = x.borrow().right.clone();
        x.borrow_mut().right = y.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().left.clone();
        if y.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().left.is_some(){
            y.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().left.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().parent = Some(x.clone());
        }
        y.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().parent = x.borrow().parent.clone();
        if x.borrow().parent.is_none(){
            //*self = Option::from(y.clone());
        }else{
            if x.borrow().key == x.borrow().parent.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().left.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().key{
                x.borrow_mut().parent.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().left = Option::from(y.as_ref().unwrap().clone());
            }else{
                x.borrow_mut().parent.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().right = Option::from(y.as_ref().unwrap().clone());
            }
        }
        y.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().left = Option::from(x.clone());
        x.borrow_mut().parent = Option::from(y.as_ref().unwrap().clone());
    }
```

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum NodeColor {
    Red,
    Black,
}

type Tree = Rc<RefCell<TreeNode<u32>>>;

type RedBlackTree= Option<Tree>;

struct TreeNode<T> {
    pub color: NodeColor,
    pub key: T,
    pub parent: RedBlackTree,
    left: RedBlackTree,
    right: RedBlackTree,
}
```

[Reproducible code](https://play.rust-lang.org/version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6556cf69984f5a932015430fa48cac6)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with use-statements, struct definitions, and code sufficient to reproduce the error. The message just tells us that the `RefCell` is already borrowed but doesn't tell us what is and the code is insufficient to determine that; we don't know the relationship between `x` and `y` or if there are other factors.

Comment: @kmdreko sorry about that. I added more info

Comment: The example is still not _reproducible_. For example, add a `main()` that would allow us to run to reproduce the same issue that you are seeing. For example, edit my attempt [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d6f18d8c078e5e08e2122b19c911bdc) (which fails with a different error) and edit the question to include the missing parts.

Comment: I made a reproducible code: [here] (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f6556cf69984f5a932015430fa48cac6)